# sending null value with parametrized queries

Tags: c#, sql

```
 public static DataTable GetBatches(long storeID, long? ProfileID)
{
    string query =
    "SELECT .... where " + (ProfileID.HasValue ? "PROFILE_ID=" + ProfileID.Value : "STORE_ID=" + storeID);
```

i want to change that query to accept parametrized values like this :

```
   List<SqlParameter> params_list = new List<SqlParameter>();
    SqlParameter param_ProfileID = new SqlParameter("@PROFILE_ID", ProfileID);
    param_StoreID.SourceColumn = "PROFILE_ID";
    param_StoreID.DbType = DbType.Int64;
    params_list.Add(param_ProfileID);
```

but what if `Profile_id` is null ? how can i do it

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the rows with a NULL value in `PROFILE_ID` along with the ones with the relevant id or do you want to be able to provide a NULL value for the parameter and retrieve all rows in this case or just the ones that have Profile_Id = NULL?

Comment: If I understand correctly your initial example, if ProfileID is null you change the WHERE condition to use STORE_ID, thus you don't use anymore the field PROFILE_ID and you don't need to build a parameter for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you use `DBNull.Value`:

```
SqlParameter param_ProfileID = new SqlParameter("ProfileID",
    (object)ProfileID ?? DBNull.Value);
```

And use `@PROFILE_ID` in the TSQL, for example:

```
where table.ProfileID = @ProfileID
```

Alternatively, use a helper tool like dapper, and forget about it:

```
return connection.Query<SomeType>(
    "select * from SomeTable where ProfileID = @ProfileID",
    new { ProfileID }).ToList();
```

(which returns a `List<SomeType>`, not a `DataTable`)

---

Re conditional searching, there are various approaches here; one is the sub-optimal:

```
where (@Foo is null or table.Foo = @Foo)
and (@Bar is null or table.Bar = @Bar)
```

which matches `@Foo` when it is provided, and `@Bar` when it is provided - but... it isn't great at hitting indexes, especially if you add more clauses. In your case, I would be tempted to do:

```
var sql = ProfileID == null
    ? "select * from Blah where StoreID = @StoreID"
    : "select * from Blah where StoreID = @StoreID and ProfileID = @ProfileID";
```

which uses optimal TSQL for the 2 scenarios. It doesn't matter if you provide unused parameters on the command, but you could also do:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StoreID", StoreID);
if(ProfileID != null) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProfileID", ProfileID);
```

Comment: no i need to return a dataTable i did this : 

  `SqlParameter param_ProfileID = new SqlParameter("@PROFILE_ID",(object)ProfileID ?? DBNull.Value);
        params_list.Add(param_StoreID);`
and the query is like this :  "where PROFILE_ID=@PROFILE_ID and STORE_ID=@STORE_ID";
now my question if @Profile_id is null would the query return an exception ?

Comment: @Sora no, that won't throw an exception, but in ANSI sql, nothing **eever** equals `null` (not even `null` itself) - so you would need TSQL to suit. I will edit to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this work around

```
List<SqlParameter> params_list = new List<SqlParameter>();
if(ProfileID==null)
{
   SqlParameter param_ProfileID = new SqlParameter("@PROFILE_ID", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
   SqlParameter param_ProfileID = new SqlParameter("@PROFILE_ID", ProfileID);
}
param_StoreID.SourceColumn = "PROFILE_ID";
param_StoreID.DbType = DbType.Int64;
params_list.Add(param_ProfileID);
```

Comment: and how should the query look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comments, the query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FFROM tbl WHERE (@Profile_Id = NULL AND Store_Id = @Store_Id) 
    OR (@Profile_Id <> NULL AND Profile_Id = @Profile_Id)
```

You can set up the parameters like this:

```
List<SqlParameter> params_list = new List<SqlParameter>();
SqlParameter param_ProfileID = new SqlParameter("@PROFILE_ID", (object)ProfileID ?? DBNull.Value);
param_StoreID.SourceColumn = "PROFILE_ID";
params_list.Add(param_ProfileID); 
SqlParameter param_StoreID = new SqlParameter("@STORE_ID", StoreId);
param_StoreID.SourceColumn = "STORE_ID";
params_list.Add(param_StoreID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first example, it seems clear that you don't need to build a parameter if your profileID variable is null, simply you write a different query

```
public static DataTable GetBatches(long storeID, long? ProfileID)
{
    List<SqlParameter> pList = new List<SqlParameter>();
    string query = "SELECT .... where ";
    if(ProfileID.HasValue)
    {
        query += "PROFILE_ID= @proID";
        SqlParameter pProfileID = new SqlParameter("@proID", SqlDbType.BigInt)
                                      .Value = ProfileID.Value;
        pList.Add(pProfileID);
    }
    else
    {
        query += "STORE_ID= @stoID";
        SqlParameter pStoreID = new SqlParameter("@stoID", SqlDbType.BigInt)
                                      .Value = storeID;
        pList.Add(pStoreID);
    }
```

If ProfileID is not null you search for it otherwise you search for StoreID and that's all.

Comment: yeah it was a fast writing mistake yes if profile id is not null i search for profile id otherwise storeid